# Unity 5.6 - C# - Adding a GameObject to another GameObject with AddComponent<T>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive

The function I'm currently working on instantiates a GameObject (using a prefab). I store this **GameObject** in a local variable

```
GameObject tmpObject;
```

Works flawlessly. Next I try to assign this GameObject to my GameObject representation of my Vive controller, which looks like this:

```
tmpObject = tmpController.gameObject.AddComponent<GameObject>() as GameObject;
```

The error that I get is that UnityEngine.GameObject cannot be converted to UnityEngine.Component.

Am I missing a simple / basic there? I tried adding a SphereCollider as per Unity's [official guidline](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) and it did work, so why can't I add GameObject? Is there a workaround to adding GameObjects to another GameObject? Any help is greatly **appreciated**!

Comment: A `GameObject` could have properies/components, however a `GameObject` can't contain other `GameObject`s. Its a different story if you want to assign a `parent` as a `GameObject` to another.

Comment: But let's say I have a plane. I can then add a cube to the plane by dragging it into the plane in the Unity hierarchy. Then the cube (GameObject) is a child of the plane (GameObject). Otherwise I get your point, but how can I assign tmpObject as a child of tmpController?

Comment: Correct, but its not a component of the parent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't add GameObject to a GameObject. That doesn't even make sense to begin with.You can only attach components. I think that you want to make a GameObject a child of another GameObject... You can use the `SetParent` function for that. See below for examples how to create a GameObject and of what you can do:

Create a new GameOBject named "BallObject"

```
GameObject a = new GameObject("BallObject");
```

Create a new GameOBject named "BrickObject"

```
GameObject b = new GameObject("BrickObject");
```

Make "BrickObject" Object parent of "BallObject" Object

```
a.transform.SetParent(b.transform);
```

Make the "BallObject" Object to be by itself. "BrickObject" Object is not it's parent anymore

```
a.transform.parent = null;
```

---

Add script/component to your "BrickObject" Object

```
b.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Comment: Yes you did. I believe Op wants to create new GameObject and assign it to the `tmpObject` variable but failed when he used `AddComponent` on a GameObject...The new keyword is the solution.